# Select minimum our_price group by test_id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query which returns the results in the following structure order by our_price ascending

```
SELECT our_price,
       mrp,
       marketplace_id,
       test_id
FROM   marketplace_test_mapping mtm
       INNER JOIN marketplace m
               ON m.id = mtm.marketplace_id
WHERE  m.city_id = 1
       AND mtm.test_id IN ( 36, 23, 43, 107,
                            121, 82 )
ORDER  BY our_price ASC;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
our_price | mrp | marketplace_id | test_id
----------+-----+----------------+--------
50         90     3                23
51         70     2                23
52         88     1                23
53         80     3                24
54         90     2                24
55         90     4                23
56         90     1                25
57         90     2                25
58         90     1                24
```

I want to fetch the minimum price for each test_id but when I group_by on `test_id`, it sorts the `marketplace_id` as well and returns the following

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT our_price,
               mrp,
               marketplace_id,
               test_id
        FROM   marketplace_test_mapping mtm
               INNER JOIN marketplace m
                       ON m.id = mtm.marketplace_id
        WHERE  m.city_id = 1
               AND mtm.test_id IN ( 36, 23, 43, 107,
                                    121, 82 )
        ORDER  BY our_price ASC) AS temp_marketplace_test_mapping
GROUP  BY test_id;
```

**Actual Output**

```
our_price | mrp | marketplace_id | test_id
----------+-----+----------------+--------
52         88     1                23
58         90     1                24
56         90     1                25
```

**Expected output**

```
our_price | mrp | marketplace_id | test_id
----------+-----+----------------+--------
50         90     3                23
53         90     3                24
56         90     1                25
```

The difference in both the results is `actual output` is sorting `marketplace_id` as well when grouping by on `test_id`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks, I added everything I thought would help and seemed necessary. Is there anything specific you need help with? I am not certain what I missed here. Can you assist?

Comment: please provide the contents of both table

Answer (score 0):

"I want to fetch the minimum price for each test_id"

```
select test_id, min(our_price) as our_price_min -- changed
from marketplace_test_mapping  mtm
inner join marketplace m on m.id=mtm.marketplace_id
where m.city_id=1 and mtm.test_id in (36,23,43,107,121,82)
group by test_id -- added
order by our_price asc;
```

Comment: But it's not the right solution. I want the column with the minimum our_price. not just the minimum our_price. This solution would result in minimum our_price for a test_id without providing other details like id, marketplace_id for that `our_price` and so on

Comment: Could you describe me (one sentence), how the output should looks like. "I want to tetch the minimum price for each test_id and ..."

Comment: One line: Find marketplace, our_price, mrp for each test_id with minimum our_price

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte (our_price,mrp,marketplace_id,test_id) AS
(SELECT our_price,mrp,marketplace_id,test_id
FROM   marketplace_test_mapping mtm
       INNER JOIN marketplace m
       ON m.id = mtm.marketplace_id
WHERE  m.city_id = 1 AND mtm.test_id IN ( 36, 23, 43, 107,121, 82 )
)
select t1.our_price, t1.mrp, t1.marketplace_id, t1.test_id from cte t1 
join (select test_id, min(our_price) our_price from cte group by test_id) t2
on t1.test_id = t2.test_id and t1.our_price = t2.our_price;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte (our_price,mrp,marketplace_id,test_id) AS
(SELECT our_price,mrp,marketplace_' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Find minimum price for each test_id, and than get the MARKETPLACE_ID and MRP for then.

```
with transactions as (
  -- get the transactions list, execute filters
  SELECT test_id, marketplace_id, mrp, our_price       
  FROM   marketplace_test_mapping mtm
  INNER JOIN marketplace m ON m.id = mtm.marketplace_id
  WHERE  m.city_id = 1
  AND mtm.test_id IN (23,36,43,82,107,121) --it's a good practice to sorta data in IN clause
)

-- if there are few marketplaces with minimum price on each test_id
-- then each of then will be shown
select a.*, b.marketplace_id, b.mrp
from (
  -- minimum price for each test_id
  select test_id, min(our_price) as our_price_min
  from transactions
  group by test_id
) a
left join transactions b on a.test_id = b.test_id and a.our_price_min = b.our_price
order by a.test_id, b.marketplace_id
```